# Can't type password for github in console

Tags: git, github, passwords

How could I go through in this situation ? When I'm typing password it's no signs like '*' but I was trying to type my password without this and it's not working. I can't type my username to github, because it's in one line with password.

[git problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCdSg.png)

Comment: Did you press the enter key multiple times after the push command? Maybe it took an empty input as your username.

Comment: I just copied text from github with echo, git init, git remote etc. and press enter.

Comment: Try typing the `git push -u origin master` command yourself. Looking at the line above, it seems you might be inputting two newlines.